# VLC doesn't show video when opened from SSH

Tags: ssh, xorg, vlc

My VLC isn't displaying the video stream when I open it in an SSH session. The audio works fine, but video doesn't.

The video **does** work under the following circumstances:

- Opening vlc using the mouse in the GUI.
- Running `vlc` in a terminal session within the graphical interface.
- Running `vlc` in a TTY opened with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>

The video **doesn't work** under the following circumstances:

- Running `vlc` from an `ssh` session.

And the following error is printed on the terminal

```
mmal_codec filter error: Failed to alloc CMA buf: fmt=Z420, size=1382400
mmal_codec filter error: Failed to alloc CMA buf: fmt=Z420, size=1382400
mmal_codec filter error: Failed to alloc CMA buf: fmt=Z420, size=1382400
…
```

All shell sessions have `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority` defined.

I tried to see what differs in these scenarios looking at the `/proc` of each process and the only meaningful difference (to me) was the `Max locked memory` in the `limits` file.

On non-functional vlc instances of vlc the min and max values were `65536` and `65536`, and on on functional instances were `496394240` and `496394240`.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 400, running a fresh install of `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`. I've tried both H.264 and H.265 and none of them worked. I've also tried setting a lot of values under `cma=` on `/boot/cmdline.txt`, but made no difference.

What am I missing on the differences between starting a program within the physical Pi and the SSH session? Something that could affect the video playback capability?